# Equal two sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that:

$\left\{ x \in X : 0 < 1 \right\} = X$ and $\left\{ x \in X : 0 > 1 \right\} = \emptyset$

where for example $X = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well...yes, isn't it obvious (wrt the usual definitions, of course)??

Comment: Which definition?

Comment: The definitions of "greater than", "smaller than", zero, one...For example, for the second set you have there: how many real number are there when $\;0>1\;$ ?

Answer (score 3):

These are true for silly reasons. $x$ is a member of the first set iff $x\in \mathbb{R}\wedge 0<1$. The second half of this conjunction has a fixed truth value (true) and no free $x$, so it's true iff the first half is; that is, if $x$ is a real number.

The second set is the same, except the statement in the conjunction with a fixed truth value is false, so there are no real numbers that make the conjunction true, so it comes out to $\emptyset$.

These are trivial, pathological cases. As a general rule, $\{x\in X:\phi\}$ for $\phi$ a sentence will be $X$ or $\emptyset$ as $\phi$ is true or false.